# logstash filter add text to output

Tags: json, elasticsearch, filter, format, logstash

I am trying to include the json input in some other json.
I can't get the hang of how the filters work and I need an example for my application.

My json input:

```
{
  "documents": {
      "name": "projects",
      "fields": {
        "done": {
          "booleanValue": false
        },
        "title": {
          "stringValue": "testtest"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2018-10-09T10:16:45.835536Z",
      "updateTime": "2018-10-09T10:17:37.550249Z"
    }
}
```

And the output should be:

```
{
 "fields": {
  "test": {
   "stringValue": "{\"documents\": {\"name\": \"projects\",\"fields\": {\"done\": {\"booleanValue\": false},\"title\": {\"stringValue\": \"testtest\"}},\"createTime\": \"2018-10-09T10:16:45.835536Z\",\"updateTime\": \"2018-10-09T10:17:37.550249Z\"}}"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
filter {
  mutate {
        rename => ["\"", "\\""]
  }
  mutate {
        rename => { "message" => "[stringValue]" }
  }
  mutate {
        rename => { "stringValue" => "[test][stringValue]"}
  }
  mutate {
        rename => { "test" => "[fields][test]"}
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@timestamp", "@version"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have input like you showed the dirtiest solution would be to modify JSON before.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "{\"fields\":{\"test\":{\"stringValue\":\"" >> newjson.json
cat yourjson.json >> newjson.json
echo -e "\"}}}" >> newjson.json
```

Comment: I am getting the input from an API and need some features from Logstash. This way I couldn't use the input plugin I need.